# Formatting a href link with appendChild, setAttribute, etc

Tags: javascript, html, href

I am attempting to populate a list with href links via javascript.

Here is an example of the html I would like to create:

```
<li> <a href="#modal-one">Complete blood count</a></li>
```

Where "#modal-one" displays a pop up.

I have used the following and several other iterations to try and create this dynamically:

```
<script>
var listItem = [];
    function createTestList() {

        var tests = results.tests;  //an array to tests to populate list
        var i;
    var j;

        for (i = 0; i < tests.length ; i++ ){ 

            listItem[i] = document.createElement("li");
            var node = document.createTextNode(tests[i].name);
            listItem[i].appendChild(node);
      listItem[i].setAttribute("href", "#modal-one");
            addOnClick(i);
            //var element = document.getElementById("div1");
            //element.appendChild(listItem[i]);

    document.body.appendChild(listItem[i]);
    console.log(listItem[i]);
        };
};
function addOnClick(j) {  //this is separate to handle the closure issue

listItem[j].onclick =  function() {loadModal(j)};
};
</script>
```

However, this code (and several others) produce:

```
<li href='#modal-one'>Complete Blood Count</li>  //note missing <a>...</a>
```

It appears there are several ways to achieve this, but nothing seems to work for me...

Comment: The reason why you're not getting the `<a>` tag is because you never create it, also I don't see where are you assigning value to `j`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are never actually adding in an anchor tag. You are creating a list-item (`li`), but you are adding an href to that list-item rather than adding an anchor node to it with that href. As such, the browser just thinks you have a list-item with an href attribute.

Consider using the following instead:

```
<script>
var listItem = [];
    function createTestList() {

        var tests = results.tests;  //an array to tests to populate list
        var i;
        var j; // Never actually used in function. Consider omitting

        for (i = 0; i < tests.length ; i++ ){ 

            // create the list item
            listItem[i] = document.createElement("li");

            // Create the anchor with text
            var anchor = document.createElement("a");
            var node = document.createTextNode(tests[i].name);
            anchor.appendChild(node);
            anchor.setAttribute("href", "#modal-one");

            // Set the onclick action
            addOnClick(i, anchor);

            // Add the anchor to the page
            listItem[i].appendChild(anchor);

            document.body.appendChild(listItem[i]);
            console.log(listItem[i]);
        };
};

// Modified "addOnClick" to include the anchor that needs the onclick
function addOnClick(j, anch) {  //this is separate to handle the closure issue

     anch.onclick =  function() {loadModal(j)};
};
</script>
```

A couple things to note:

1. I have modified your `addOnClick()` function because it is the anchor element that needs the *onclick*, not the list item.
2. I have added in the creation of an anchor element rather than simply creating a list item and adding the href to that.

Answer (score 2):

I do not see creating **a** element, change code to:

```
var aNode=document.createElement("a");
aNode.innerText=tests[i].name;
aNode.setAttribute("href", "#modal-one");
listItem[i].appendChild(aNode);
```

You can change also click method, to use it on **a** not on **li**

```
function addOnClick(j) { 

  listItem[j].querySelector("a").addEventListener("click",function(e) {

     e.preventDefault();//this prevent for going to hash in href  
     loadModal(j);

  });

};
```

Comment: I didn't try this.

Answer (score 0):

Okay. I missed the anchor tag. My bad...

Spencer's answer came close, but I had to make few changes to get it work in my instance.

The final working code (and honestly I am not sure why it works) is:

```
<script>
var listItem = [];
    function createTestList() {

        var tests = results.tests;
        var i;
    //var j;

        for (i = 0; i < tests.length ; i++ ){ 

             // create the list item
        listItem[i] = document.createElement("li");

        // Create the anchor with text
        var anchor = document.createElement("a");
        anchor.setAttribute("href", "#modal-one");
        var node = document.createTextNode(tests[i].name);
        anchor.appendChild(node);


        // Set the onclick action
        addOnClick(i);

        // Add the anchor to the page
        listItem[i].appendChild(anchor);

        document.getElementById("demo").appendChild(listItem[i]);  //added the list to a separate <div> rather than body. It works fine like this.
        console.log(listItem[i]);
        };
};
function addOnClick(j) {  //this is separate to handle the closure issue

//didn't need the additional code beyond this
listItem[j].onclick =  function() {loadModal(j)};
};
 </script>
```

Thanks to all and Spencer thanks for the thoroughly commented code. It helps!!!

Comment: if Spencer answer helped You then check it as right instead of pasting own answer. Main problem with "a" element was solved in his answer.

Comment: @MaciejSikora, thanks for arguing for my answer :P Jeff, glad you got it working. Just as a heads up, if that is a direct copy and paste of the code you are using, you should change `addOnClick(i, anchor);` in the for-loop to simply say `addOnClick(i);`. You are passing the index/iterator and the anchor node/element to the `addOnClick(...)` function, but that function is only declared to accept one parameter. Additionally, you can optimize the code by defining `var eleAppendLocation = document.getElementById(...);` above the loop and replacing the getElement call in your loop with that var.

Comment: I have now selected Spencer's as the "answer" but it did need an unforeseen tweak which I wanted to document.. Spencer, that was typo with addClick(i, anchor) and I have now corrected. Will also try optimization suggestions. Thanks all.